# Blank screen in flutter app once application back from permission setting screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on app where i am asking for location permission.
If user click deny i am navigating user to setting screen so that they can manually turn on the location. But when i change the location permission from setting screen and click back and navigate to application blank screen appears and also i am not able to detect the change permission status.
Below is code :

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';


    class LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver{
      PermissionStatus _status;
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance
            .addPostFrameCallback((_) => afterFirstLayout(context));    
      }
void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context){
     PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.locationAlways]).then(__onStatusRequested);
  }


  void __onStatusRequested(Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> statuses){
    if(statuses != PermissionStatus.granted){
       PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();
    }else{
      _status = PermissionStatus.granted;

    }
  }
```

Comment: You use back button physical back arrow down on app? Right? When you click back button it will pop() current screen and if nothing is there on stack then app will show blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have used. Take a look hope it will help

```
void _askPermission() {
    PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
        [PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]).then(_onStatusrequested);
  }

 void _onStatusrequested(Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> statuses) {
    final status = statuses[PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse];
    if (status == PermissionStatus.neverAskAgain) {
      // openSettingsDialog();
      setState(() {
        isPermissionIgnored = true;
      });
      _updateStatus(_status);
    } else if (status == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      setState(() {
        isPermissionIgnored = false;
      });

      _updateStatus(status);
    } else if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      setState(() {
        isPermissionIgnored = false;
      });

      _updateStatus(status);
    }
  }
void _updateStatus(PermissionStatus status) {
if (status != _status) {
  _status = status;
  print(_status);
}
print(status);
}
```